# BackgroundPanel.java with Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, background, jpanel

recently I discover this [BackgroundPanel.java](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) and I want to know how I can use it with netbeans, I create a package called clases, and inside it I have the class.

In other package (vistas) I have the jFrame, and I try different ways to add this "panel" to my jFrame, but nothing works. I know that I have to add this to initComponents()

```
    private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>
```

and add the BackgroundPanel in jFrame in setContentPane, but how?

Someone can help me? thanks you very much

Comment: If you just want to use the background as the content pane, call `setContentPane` passing an instance of the background pane to it BEFORE you call `initComponents`.  Make sure that the project containing the background pane is linked to the current project

Answer (score 0):

(note: your description does not make any sense, so I am doing a little mind reading trick here and making a few assumptions about your intentions and your code).

1. If your JFrames are generated by Netbeans, just drag the BackgroundPanel.java from sources on to the design view, as you would from the palette (the project must be compiled in order for this to work). That's the simplest way.
2. If you need the BackgroundPanel to be the contentPane, drag it to the design view but outside of any visible component. The code building the panel should appear in the initComponents() method (under the name of backgroundPanel1), but the panel itself should not yet become visible. Now choose the JFrame, find "contentPane" in it the properties window and choose the backgroundPanel1.

Comment: I try to do what you say, but dont work, this is what happen [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QoWQLLIt7zA)
My idea is add a scalable background image

Comment: @user1794441: "this video is private, sorry about that"?